# Interactive Image/Graphic in React/Html

Tags: html, reactjs, svg

Im fairly new to react/html and im trying to make an interactive Graphic/Image, such that when a mouse hovers over a circle it highlights a colour and when i click it turns to a colour. Is it possible to do this? Can i get some advice on how its possible to do this without hardcoding different images to load once one (or more) have been clicked.

Thanks Heaps!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you create a circle Component
with onMouseEnter  and onMouseLeave methods to change the display color when mouse enters and leaves the circle Component

and then you can use an onclick method to change the color when it is clicked.